# Replace the reoccurring adjacent characters with other character

Tags: c

#### Problem

If you have two reoccurring character, which you will specify in your input, for example, you enter "*", you will replace " ** " on every single line, when adjacent with other character like "A", how would you do that?

I thought of using an array to store every single character, and go through the array using index `i`, check if `arr[i] = arr[i+1]="*"`, and simply replace it.

But WHICH ONE will you replace and how you making sure, and how you replace it? Since before two index occupied by " *" and now we are replacing it with only one.

Comment: I am lost by your description. Can you use proper formatting to your question? So the user enters `"**"` or `**` ? You wan to print `" ** "` or ` ** ` or you want to print the next inputted string with some substitution done? ? Please post example input and example output using proper formatting? Please post what have you tried? You want to replace what? If you have a string `abc**def` and want to make `abc ** def`, you need to find `**`, then move all characters to the right, then input ` ** ` into the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are asking. In your case if you have `"**"` you want to replace those 2-characters with `'A'`. That is quite easy to do. You will simply loop over each character of input delaying an evaluation of the sequence until you have 2 characters read (simply saving `current` as `last` at the end of the loop and using `last` as a flag will suffice)

Then if `current == last` and `last == find` character, replace the sequence and get the next input character, otherwise, just output the `last` character.

A short example which takes the sequence character to `find` as the first argument (using `'*'` if no arguments is provided) and the `repl` character as the second arguments (using `'A'` if no argument is provided) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c,                                  /* current char */
        find = argc > 1 ? *argv[1] : '*',   /* sequential char to find */
        repl = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : 'A',   /* replacement for seq chars */
        last = 0;                           /* previous char */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {        /* read each char */
        if (last) {                         /* is last set? */
            if (c == last && last == find) {/* do we have sequence? */
                putchar (repl);             /* output replacement */
                last = 0;                   /* set last 0 */
                continue;                   /* go get next char */
            }
            else    /* otherwise */
                putchar (last);     /* just output last */
        }
        last = c;   /* set last = current */
    }
    if (last)           /* if last wasn't zeroed */
        putchar (last); /* just output final char */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "There are two ** in the sky" | ./bin/replseqchar
There are two A in the sky

$ echo "There are two *** in the sky" | ./bin/replseqchar
There are two A* in the sky

$ echo "There are two **** in the sky" | ./bin/replseqchar
There are two AA in the sky
```

or with a differenent replacement using `'-'` instead of `'A'`,

```
$ echo "There are two **** in the sky" | ./bin/replseqchar '*' -
There are two -- in the sky
```